# Rails avatar uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, carrierwave, jcrop, avatar

I'm looking for the best way for loading user avatar for rails app.

There is some of important cases:

- load images from web or local
- allow user crop image at preview window (with Jcrop for example)
- save several sizes of avatar 64x64, 128x128, etc (Carrierwave or Paperclip no mater)
- easy styling and customizing

I found
https://github.com/ging/avatars_for_rails but interesting in any alternatives or good samples.

Comment: Sounds pretty good.  If you wanted to be *cough*lazy*cough* you could also display avatars for users via Gravatar.  Sounds like avatars are a major feature of your app, though, so that may not be a fit, but just noting.

Comment: but it's work around, and hard to load avatar for user without gravatar account ^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please checkout http://odysseyonrails.com/articles/10. It has a demo code using paperclip and jcrop that fits all your needs.

Answer (score 2):

[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) (most popular)
[Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly)

Comment: but it's only server side. How show for user cropping proccess/region on client side?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this tutorial here](http://youtu.be/1tTzkltJgiA?t=12m51s) (skip to 12:50 to see if it's even what you're after). It uses JCrop on the client side of a Rails application for the user to crop their avatar and then save it on the server side.

Hope this helps!